# Why testcafe runs tests twice?

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I just don't understand, why testcafe runs this test twice in my case :

MainApp.ts :

```
const getUrl = ClientFunction(() => window.location.href);
class MainApp {
  async login(url:string) {
    await t.expect(getUrl()).eql(url);
  }} 
export default new MainApp();
```

Test.ts :

```
import MailosaurClient from "mailosaur";
import { Selector, t } from "testcafe";
import MainApp from "./MainApp";
const testUrl = `https://www.google.com/`;
fixture("fixture")
  .page("https://www.google.com/")
  .beforeEach(async (t) => {
    console.log("test");
  })
  .disablePageCaching("fixture");

test("Test", async (t) => {
  console.log("Starting test");
  await MainApp.login(
    testUrl
  );
```

Comment: I ran your test, and it works as expected. So, there is no error in your test code. Probably, the error is in the way you run your test (in your terminal command or in your runner file).

Comment: @AlexKamaev Thank you for your help, can you share your testcafe runner setup?

Comment: @AlexKamaev you said that it works as expected. So, does it runs for you only once?

Comment: Yes, it only runs once for me. However, I run tests without the runner file and only with a terminal command: `testcafe chrome test.ts`. Please share your runner file. I'll try to reproduce the issue on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine not running twice just update node and install testcafe and

type `npx testcafe <browser> <path>`